# can't add plugin org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I am having some problems with PhoneGap 3.0
Everything was working as should on PhoneGap 2.9

Now I upgraded to 3.0 And created a new PhoneGap Project.

```
$> phonegap create new_project
```

added to config.xml :

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

and for index.html I used the full example from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition_full_example

then

```
$> phonegap build android
```

I imported the project to Eclipse and checked the following :
AndroidManifest.xml has

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

xml/config.xml has

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

I also used this cmd :

```
$> phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

and that created the package src/

```
org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

now when I run my app.
I got the Following errors :

```
I/System.out(15155): Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker.
D/PluginManager(15155): exec() call to unknown plugin: Geolocation
```

error Trace :

```
09-14 18:07:50.185: W/System.err(28211): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker
09-14 18:07:50.195: W/System.err(28211):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-14 18:07:50.195: W/System.err(28211):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
09-14 18:07:50.195: W/System.err(28211):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
09-14 18:07:50.195: W/System.err(28211):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.getClassByName(PluginEntry.java:117)
09-14 18:07:50.195: W/System.err(28211):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:93)
09-14 18:07:50.195: W/System.err(28211):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:267)
09-14 18:07:50.205: W/System.err(28211):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:221)
09-14 18:07:50.205: W/System.err(28211):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:216)
09-14 18:07:50.205: W/System.err(28211):    at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
09-14 18:07:50.205: W/System.err(28211):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
09-14 18:07:50.205: W/System.err(28211):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
09-14 18:07:50.205: W/System.err(28211):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:107)
09-14 18:07:50.215: W/System.err(28211):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:136)
09-14 18:07:50.215: W/System.err(28211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 18:07:50.215: W/System.err(28211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-14 18:07:50.215: W/System.err(28211):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:780)
09-14 18:07:50.215: W/System.err(28211):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
09-14 18:07:50.225: W/System.err(28211): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cordova/geolocation/GeoBroker
09-14 18:07:50.225: W/System.err(28211):    ... 17 more
09-14 18:07:50.225: W/System.err(28211): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker
09-14 18:07:50.225: W/System.err(28211):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-14 18:07:50.225: W/System.err(28211):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-14 18:07:50.225: W/System.err(28211):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-14 18:07:50.235: W/System.err(28211):    ... 17 more
```

and the Javascript function onError()
alert with code:null & message:

Any suggestions ?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks it's strange, but it was solved by following the steps from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com).

You need to download Cordova Android from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android).
Then run these commands to build cordova-dev.jar:

```
android update project -p . -t android-17
ant jar
```

This will create `cordova-dev.jar`. Alternatively you can download the jar from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zb0ep22huu9x2dc/5MUT8BqD6b).

Copy `cordova-dev.jar` to libs folder in the Android project in eclipse and add it to the project classpath.
    Now all the compilation errors will be resolved, and the project will compile successfully.

Comment: How to add the jar file on the project classpath?