# Can not load phonegap geoloacation plugin. Add .jar to classpath?

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I have **exactly** the same problem as [mohheadeer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802580/cant-add-plugin-org-apache-cordova-geolocation-geobroker). The only difference is that my project did not exist in phonegap 2.9 before.

I'm using android studios and added the path to the downloaded .jar in `file->project structure->SDKs` but it doesn't solve the problem. Is this the right point to add th path?

Just like mohheader I find this solution kind of strange. Does anybody have another idea? What is the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By going below mentioned site download the phone gap/cordova latest one

[http://phonegap.com/]

by going to eclipse

Help-->Install New Software

click on Add button,in that paste the url which i am providing and download the phonegap plugins to eclipse

below is the which i'm providing

https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

and after that press cntl+N in that choose phonegap for andriod project ,click on Next button

where you can find 'phonegap configuartion' and select the radio button 'enter the path to installed phonegap'
and select the path where the phonegap is placed and after then try to place you code and execute in the mobile/emulator

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Maneti but it didn't really help me out.

In the end I did it like [Roman Nurik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367994/javascript-geolocation-on-android-doesnt-work) and it worked well. I'm not 100% sure if this solution works with the phonegap api but I don't need the api since I develope phonegap apps for ios and android (they support w3c geolocation standard, just like most of the browsers -> http://caniuse.com/geolocation)